# Replacing string with sed is working but not saving the file

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a file, named `matteo_test.sh`, which contains the string `/nettools/python_64`.
I want to replace this string with `/nettools/python_release/python278/`.

I do the following:

```
original_str='/nettools/python_64'
replace_str='/nettools/python_release/python278/'
sed "s~$original_str~$replace_str~" matteo_test.sh
```

When I execute that, the command line outputs me the entire content of the file `matteo_test.sh`. Under this outputted content, I can see that the string has been correctly replaced.

However, the content of the file itself has not been modified because if I re-open it, I still see the old string inside.

It seems that the `sed` command I execute is making the replacement into a string containing the entire content of the file, instead of replacing into the file itself.

I'm not an expert of Unix Shell, so I'm probably missing a very simple point: can anyone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

My purpose is to replace that string into the file.

Comment: use `sed -i` to update the content in a file

Comment: @Kalanidhi thanks a lot, it worked. Please write it as answer so I will accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try  `sed -i` to save the content in file instead of printing the output in terminal

Refer `man sed`

```
 -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

              edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

**With backup** 
If you want to take backup with existing file using `sed -i.bak`.

**Example:**

```
sed -i.bak 's/search/patter/' file_name.txt
```

`file_name.txt` content will be changed with updated content, but still you have a old content in `file_name.txt.bak`

**Note :**
Before posting any questing , please search `google` related to that question and read `man` page ,so that you can save your time.